# How render a Flask WTF HTML 5 widget?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to use the html 5 widgets of Flask to build a [RangeInput](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/v0.8.3/) (search for "range" to find it).
I think I'm missing something in the HTML template because it renders like that:

[image: It does not create a form but text !]

As you can see, it's not what I wanted: I was expecting something like that:

[image]

So I think the error isn't that tricky but I cannot find it. Here are my different files:

```
__author__ = 'laurentmeyer'

# That's my main class, don't be afraid, all is local, you cannot hack anything

from MySQL import MySQL
from flask import Flask, render_template
from Form import Form;

mysql = MySQL();
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'Laurent'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'laurent'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'Houses'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from Offers;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    form = Form(csrf_enabled=False);
    if data is None:
        return "No data"
    else:
            return render_template('DB template.html',form = form, offers = data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My HTML template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tableau des maisons</title>
</head>
<body>
<form><p>Test: {{ form.ImportanceOfPrice }} </p></form>
<!--<table>{% for house in offers %}<tr><td>Titre: {{house[0]}}</td><td>Lien: <a href="{{house[1]}}">{{house[1]}}</a></td></tr>{% endfor %}</table>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is my Form.py (very simple):

```
__author__ = 'laurentmeyer'

from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_wtf.html5 import RangeInput

class Test(Form):
    ImportanceOfPrice = RangeInput(0.1)
```

Comment: I think you want `from Form import Test` instead of `from Form import Form` in your main module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following code should be useful:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DecimalRangeField


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


class TestForm(Form):
    price_importance = DecimalRangeField('Price Importance')


@app.route("/")
def home():
    form = TestForm(csrf_enabled=False)
    return render_template('tpl.html', form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Template tpl.html, which, by default, must be placed into a folder 'templates':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <p>{{ form.price_importance.label }}: {{ form.price_importance }}</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your code contains some errors:

- Python does not require semi-colons to terminate statements.
- You don't import the right form class (you should import the *Test* form class)
- In a form class, you should usually declare *fields* (which are rendered via widgets)

Comment: Ok, few of observations are false : it was already in templates, the Test was already imported (but during my tests, it happened that I didn't import it anymore). I think the error comes from the fact that I forgot the "field". Thanks for your correction, you saved my day !

Comment: Any suggestions on how to have the selected value presented in-line with the slider?