# WTForms: How to render an HTML5 Widget?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to use the WTForms color input field.

This is how I define the form:

```
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import ColorInput

class ColoursForm(Form):
   background_color = ColorInput()
```

This is the view:

```
@app.route("/colours/<token>/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_colours(token):
   form = ColoursForm(request.form)
   if request.method == 'GET':
       return render_template('colours_edit.html', form=form, token=token)
   else:  # Request = post

      return redirect(url_for('view_scoreboard', token=token))
```

In my Jinja2 Template (colours_edit.html) I do this:

```
<p> {{ form.background_color }} Pick a color here </p>
```

However, it doesn't render an HTML Color-picker as expected, instead I see this in the rendered HTML:

> <wtforms.widgets.html5.ColorInput object at 0x10b836e90> Pick a color
> here

Why is the input not being rendered?

Comment: Can you please add more of your HTML code and the .py view as well? Also I don't understand where it show the <wtforms.widgets.html5.ColorInput object at 0x10b836e90> Color for background? Once you select it? where you return it?

Comment: @FedericoBaù I've added some more info. Is it clearer now?

Comment: `<p> {{ form.background_color() }} Pick a color here </p>`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb That results in 
`TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field'`

Comment: I think you getting closer to find a solution. I think it misses the 'color' input. When excatly do you get this error?When you submit the Form?

Comment: @FedericoBaù I get this error when doing a GET on the view. I'm not submitting the form.

Comment: Check this OS --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455088/how-render-a-flask-wtf-html-5-widget/23455918

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked it out. There were 2 problems with my code:

I was missing () here:

```
<p> {{ form.background_color() }} Pick a color here </p>
```

The form should look this:

```
class ColoursForm(Form):
"""Used when editing scoreboard colours"""
   background_color = StringField(widget=ColorInput())
```

From [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877861/output-type-number-with-flask-wtforms).

Finally, I've got to say that the WTForms documentation is not very good on this. Some examples would certainly help.